# Calling super static method from designated initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

[SKNode node] returns a initlialized node. (
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKNode/node )

If i subclass SKNode:

@interface MyClass : SKNode

And then in my designated initializer inside MyClass i call the super designated initializer (a class method).

```
@implementation MyClass
{ 
    MyScene _MyScene;
}

- (instancetype)initWithScene:(MyScene *)myScene
{
    _MyScene = myScene;
    if (self = [SKNode node]) { // HERE I GET ERROR
     }
     return self;

}
```

ERROR: Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parenthesis
And if i change it to:

```
if ((self = [SKNode node]))
```

I get: incompatible pointer types assigning to (MyClass *) from (SKNode *)
What is the way to call super designated initializer if its a class method? I also tried 
calling self = (MyClass *)[SKNode node] but i get an strange error.

Comment: By the way: Do not access the _MyScene instance variable (which should really be named lowercase _myScene) before You have assigned the result of [super init] to 'self'. As a memory optimization, init can give you back a different object than you were originally called on. If that happened, you'd not have set the scene on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get: incompatible pointer types assigning to (MyClass *) from (SKNode *)

The problem is that `[SKNode node]` allocates and initializes in instance of `SKNode`, which means that you don't get the opportunity to turn that object into an instance of your own subclass. You get the incompatible pointer error because you're trying to assign a `SKNode *` to `self`, which is of type `MyClass *`.

Instead, you need to do the allocation yourself, so that enough space is left over for your instance variables after the superclass does its initialization. So, do something like:

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {
//...
}
```

> I also tried calling self = (MyClass *)[SKNode node] but i get an strange error.

That's basically the same problem. Casting `[SKNode node]` to type `MyClass *` doesn't change the fact that the object itself is an instance of `SKNode`, not an instance of `MyClass`. Again, you need to make an instance of `MyClass` (using `+alloc`) and then call the superclass's (`SKNode`) initializer, and *then* do the `MyClass` initialization.

Comment: Its works, but i dont clearly understand why on other objects i call always [super designatedInitializer:] and in this if i inspect "init" i gets to - (id)init; on @interface NSObject <NSObject>, so at the top level, so it never passes inside [SKnode node] wich is the method that return the node initialized...?

Comment: +node is not an initializer (and definitely not the *designated* initializer). So rules that apply to init methods don't apply to it. +node is a factory method that internally eventually calls +alloc and -init. By the time your -initWithScene: is called, +alloc has already been called, so you don't want to call it a second time by calling +node. You'd be allocing a *second* object (of type SKNode, apparently) and calling that.

Comment: I mean, imagine there is a NSLog(@"Hello!); inside [SKNode node]. Doing self = [super init] seams that this hello never will be printed since init just exists in NSObject.

Comment: SKNode is a subclass of NSObject. As such, it inherits all the methods NSObject declares, including -init. If an object doesn't like the way NSObject implements -init, it will provide its own version internally. But that's an internal detail, and as such, it will not be declared in the header a second time. If an object inherits -init, you can usually assume you can use that method.

Comment: So the last question to clarify all: Whats the difference then to do [[SKNode alloc] init] or [SNode node] ?

Comment: There's no difference between `[[SKNode alloc] init]` and `[SKNode node]`, but notice that you don't call `[[SKNode alloc] init]` in your `-initWithScene:` -- you only call `[super init]` (i.e. `[SKNode init]`). That's because `[MyClass alloc]` has already been called, and it created the object that you're now in the process of initializing.

Comment: @Caleb the problem is not that an instance of SKNode is allocated by +node. +node allocates whatever subclass you send it to (hence the instancetype return type). If the OP had written self = [MyClass node]; there would be no error message. Though it'd still be wrong because as you said the OP wants to call -init, while +node is equivalent to +alloc followed by -init. It's probably implemented as +(instancetype) node { return [[self alloc] init]; } (assuming ARC here, otherwise there'd also be an autorelease).

Comment: You get the problem with `[SKNode node]` and not with `[super init]` because the first is a designated factory method (it's a class method that creates a new instance of SKNode) while the latter is a designated init method (it's an instance method, that initializes an already existing instance of SKNode)

Comment: @uliwitness It doesn't matter what the superclass is, sending `+node` to the superclass will still result in allocating an object of the wrong type because, by definition, the superclass of `MyClass` is not `MyClass`. I'm pretty sure we're on the same page here.

Comment: Yes, on the same page. :-) I intentionally wrote [MyClass node], not [super node].

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to:

```
if (self = [super init]) {
...
```

You don't want to create a SKNode object but by calling: `[SKNode node]` you trying to do that.